# Android Client /Java Server and Mysql DataBase Tcp Socket Programming

Tags: java, android, mysql, sockets, tcp

I have an **Android Client** which can send a Image to **Java server** on **TCP socket** , Java server insert's the Image received into MySQL as a Long Blob and also client ID. Now I want that the Java server to retrieve all the images saved in MySQL for a given client II, and send all the Images to Android client.

Can anyone give an example or any Idea for doing this?

Comment: I wouldn't close this one as "Too broad", since a lot of folks ask questions like "How do I talk to MySQL from Android?" and the question has a specific answer: "Create API, using xml/json/whatever".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some API on your server. I would go with the REST JSON API, so that your Android client will make a request to the following URL:

```
http://yourhost.com/api/images
```

And the response would be:

```
[
  {"name":"foo", "url":"http://yourhost.com/foo"}, ...
]
```

I believe you can achieve that with many Java server-side frameworks, but the idea behind that is: your server receives a request for images, fetches data from DB and writes a response as json/xml/protobuf/whatever your like/.